# how to get/generate a Paypal refresh_token

Tags: paypal, token, refresh-token

Access tokens only last a few hours and must be "refreshed" on a regular basis.  According to the developer documentation a "refresh_token" is user to do this, however I am unable find where one obtains a refresh_token.  Can anyone help?